# How to get call logs in iPhone like truecaller

Tags: ios

Is it possible to get call logs in iOS just like **truecaller** app does? As far as I know, Apple does not allow you to fetch call logs. Then how does truecaller maintain its call log list?

Comment: Check out this may helpful

https://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/